# How to map properly with Automapper?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, castle-windsor, automapper, automapper-2

I'm working on an application which uses Automapper, Unit Of Work, Entity Framework 5, ASPNET MVC 4, WebApi and Windsor Castle from Nuget.

I'm not sure if I should map this or it should be mapped by Automapper automatically

```
public IEnumerable<StoreDto> Get()
{
    return Uow.Stores.GetAll().OrderBy(s => s.Name);
}
```

`Uow.Stores.GetAll().OrderBy(s => s.Name)` returns an `IOrderedQueryable<Store>`.

I'm receiving the error message

> *Cannot convert expresion type IOrderedQueryable to type IEnumerable*

Should I do a foreach and convert each object returned by `GetAll` to `StoreDto` with `Mapper.Map` method of Automapper? Wouldn't Automapper convert it for me?

This is how I'm using Automapper and how I'm registering it. Please let me know if something should/can be improved.

`AutomapperInstaller.cs`:

```
 public class AutoMapperInstaller : IWindsorInstaller
    {
        public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
        {
            Mapper.Initialize(x => x.ConstructServicesUsing(container.Resolve));

            RegisterProfilesAndResolvers(container);
            RegisterMapperEngine(container);
        }

        private void RegisterMapperEngine(IWindsorContainer container)
        {
            container.Register(Component.For<IMappingEngine>().Instance(Mapper.Engine));
        }

        private void RegisterProfilesAndResolvers(IWindsorContainer container)
        {
            // register value resolvers
            container.Register(AllTypes.FromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()).BasedOn<IValueResolver>());

            // register profiles
            container.Register(AllTypes.FromThisAssembly().BasedOn<Profile>());
            var profiles = container.ResolveAll<Profile>();

            foreach (var profile in profiles)
            {
                Mapper.AddProfile(profile);
            }
        }
```

`WebWindsorInstaller`:

```
internal class WebWindsorInstaller : IWindsorInstaller
    {
        public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
        {
            container.Register(Component
                .For<RepositoryFactories>()
                .ImplementedBy<RepositoryFactories>()
                .LifestyleSingleton());

            container.Register(Component
                .For<IRepositoryProvider>()
                .ImplementedBy<RepositoryProvider>()
                .LifestylePerWebRequest());

            container.Register(Component
                .For<IProjUow>()
                .ImplementedBy<ProjUow>()
                .LifestylePerWebRequest());

            container.Register(Classes
                .FromAssemblyContaining<Api.StoresController>()
                .BasedOn<IHttpController>()
                .If(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Controller"))
                .LifestylePerWebRequest());

            RegisterMapping(container, store);
        }

        private void RegisterMapping(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
        {
            Mapper.CreateMap<Store, StoreDto>();
        }
}
```

`Store.cs`:

```
public class Store
    {
        public Store()
        {
            this.Branches = new List<Branch>();
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public System.Data.Spatial.DbGeography Location{ get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Branch> Branches{ get; set; }
    }
```

`StoreDto.cs` (same as Store by now)

```
public class StoreDto
    {
        public StoreDto()
        {
            this.Branches = new List<BranchDto>();
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public System.Data.Spatial.DbGeography Location{ get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<BranchDto> Branches{ get; set; }
    }
```

And this is how I'm calling the installer in `IocConfig.cs`:

```
Container = new WindsorContainer()
                .Install(new AutoMapperInstaller())
                .Install(new ControllersInstaller());
```

I'm not sure if I should include there

```
.AddFacility<FactorySupportFacility>()
```

Comment: Can you paste the exact error message?

Comment: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IOrderedQueryable<Proj.Model.Store>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Proj.UI.Dto.StoreDto>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: What statement is causing this error? If it is from a call to `Mapper.Map`, can you please post your automapper profile?

Comment: The first one on my post, the return, which I understand since GetAll returns an IOrderedQueryable and the methods returns an IEnumerable< >, but I'm not sure if Automapper + Castle should resolve this automatically.

BTW, if I'm using Mapper.CreateMap<Store, StoreDto>();

Should I use the inverse as well?
Mapper.CreateMap<StoreDto, Store>();

Thanks!